# How do I access a url parameter inside a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that needs to access a url parameter. However, I can't figure out how to access the parameter. Here is what I have so far:

Controller:

```
function CustomerCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route) {

// var customer_id = $routeParams.id; // this doesn't work
// var customer_id = $route.current.params.id; // this doesn't work
var customer_id = '58'; // this clearly works

$http({
    url: 'customers/'+customer_id+'/info',
    method: "POST"
})
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.name = data; })
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.status = status; });
}
```

App:

```
var customer = {
    name: 'customer',
    url: '/customer',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/customer/customer.html',
    controller: 'CustomerCtrl'
};

var customer_info = {
    name: 'customer.info',
    parent: customer,
    url: '/:id/info'
    views: {
        view1: { templateUrl: "views/customer/view1.html" },
        view2: { templateUrl: "views/customer/view2.html" }
    }
};

$stateProvider
    .state(customer)
    .state(customer_info);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: $routeParams.id should work. According to your implementation, you can pass the parameter like this /customer?id=58, then the CustomerCtrl can see the parameter.

Comment: I'm passing the parameter like this: ``<tr ng-model="customer_id" ng-click="setRoute('/customer/'+customer_id+'/info')">``. So it ends up being ``setRoute('/customer/58/info')``. It tried writing it the way you suggested, but it still didn't work.

Comment: customer_id is not query param, it is a part of the url, try <tr ng-model="customer_id" ng-click="setRoute('/customer/'+customer_id+'/info?id='+ customer_id)">

Answer (score 1):

It's actually even easier than you thought.   You're using the ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which uses states instead of the default router.

```
function CustomerCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route) {
```

should be:

```
function CustomerCtrl($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {
```

then:

```
var customer_id = $stateParams.id;
```

Comment: This does work, well. Try something like: `myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state',  function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {`. You'll then have `$stateParams.customer_id` which equates to `:customer_id` from your state router.

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day confusing myself by trying to find an angular solution to this seemingly simple, common problem. Most of you probably already figured this out, but the solution is to just use plain old javascript:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var customer_id = pathArray[3];
$scope.customer_id = customer_id
```

So simple, yet I feel like an idiot for not thinking about this from the beginning.